# Логика для генератора паззлов c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Программа должна работать следующим образом :

1. В приложение WinForms загружается исходная картинка.
2. Загружается нужная сетка паззла.
3. Программа разбивает картинку по сетке и перемешивает элементы

Каким образом такое можно было бы реализовать на C#? Из идей пока что только пробежаться по пнг файлу сетки, сохранить координаты пикселей границ элементов в массив и по этим координатам разбивать картинку. Но каким образом оформить эти координаты в элемент паззла?

Comment: Начните с решения на бумаге. Вот прямо с листом контуров, картинки, карандаша и ножниц. Как будете действовать? - составьте алгоритм.

Comment: Простой класс, который хранит X, Y и картинку. Этого достаточно, чтобы знать, где был вырезан кусок. Далее создать коллекцию этих экземпляров и готово, вот и вся модель данных.

Comment: Я вместо сетки делал шаблон, где каждый кусочек пазла раскрашен в разный цвет, так проще определить их края и потом сформировать шаблон для каждого кусочка.